# can I serve a python 2.7 and a 3.6 django website at the same time with the same User database?

Tags: python, django, channel

I have an old python 2.7 with Django 1.8 website running for years, it would be a lot of works to do if I upgrade it to python 3 and a new version Django, since there are a lot of apps on it not compatible with python 3.
And I need to use channels. It looks like I'd better use python 3.6+ and the new version of Django. So I could only create a new site rather than create an app for the old website.
Can I serve a new website, and share the old database to it so that the users can use the new one directly?

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem. Just check what isolation level you have set (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-isolation-levels?view=sql-server-2017) and make sure that it is appropriate for your use case (assumption here is that python2 and python3 run concurently and keep using the same DB). But generally this should be set to a reasonable choice out of the box